# APi call and render text result

Tags: typescript, react-native, api

Below is the call to the api and the `console.log` returns what I want, but I want to return the result in the `<Text>{callOnmoTermsApi}</Text>` The error I am getting is

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.
```

When I change the Text to a Button and console.log the onPress action it also shows what I want! Please help!!!

```
import { NavigationState } from '@react-navigation/routers';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationParams, NavigationSwitchProp } from 'react-navigation';
import { onmoTerms } from '@/api/authApi';
import OnmoButton from '@/components/Buttons/OnmoButton';

interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationSwitchProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>;
}

const OnmoTermsAndCond = () => {
  const [terms] = useState('');
  const callOnmoTermsApi = () => {
    onmoTerms()
      .then((resp: any) => {
        if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
          console.log('terms ', resp);
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('timeout terms ', resp);
        }, 500);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>{callOnmoTermsApi}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default OnmoTermsAndCond;
```

Comment: `callOnmoTermsApi` is a function, to set text, make a state, and  update it with API's result after successfull fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the response in a state, you could use useEffect for that, passing an empty array to useEffect will cause it to be called only on mount

```
import { NavigationState } from '@react-navigation/routers';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationParams, NavigationSwitchProp } from 'react-navigation';
import { onmoTerms } from '@/api/authApi';
import OnmoButton from '@/components/Buttons/OnmoButton';

interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationSwitchProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>;
}

const OnmoTermsAndCond = () => {
const [terms] = useState('');
const [omno, setOmno] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    onmoTerms()
      .then((resp: any) => {
        if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
          console.log('terms ', resp);
          setOmno(resp)
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('timeout terms ', resp);
          setOmno(resp)
        }, 500);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>{omno}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default OnmoTermsAndCond;
```